# Next.js app routing not working after deployment to cPanel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cpanel, buddy-works

I just deployed my next app on cPanel using buddy works and Github. The overall process was fluent and working properly and i was able to upload my .next folder to public.html folder of cPanel. But after uploading the files and visiting the domain i found that the only page that was correctly rendered was the first page with the route ('/'). On clicking on other routes i was met with the following error page

[image: Error displayed on all other routes]

Only after adding .html extension to the end of the route i was able to get the desired page. Attaching the screenshot for that here

[image]

I have gone through all the next js documentation available and i still am not able to sort this issue out properly. If anyone can point to what i am doing wrong here would be great help. Thanks!

Comment: What build command did you use? Is it `next export` or `next build`? Are you trying to navigate to that page manually by typing in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: I used both **next export** and **next build** while following the Next documentation. No i am clicking on the designated buttons to route to other screens , which is working fine on Local host and Netlify deployment. Routing shows 404 Error when deployed on namecheap.

Comment: `next export` and `next build`? You used both of them?

Comment: Yes i used both.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. @WakasAbbasid can you please tell me how you fixed it?

Comment: @mikasa Refer to ShubhamWaje's answer below.

Answer (score 9):

You have to add `trailingSlash` key in `next.config.js` as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  ...
}
```

and then build your project in the same way you are building now.

Comment: I have been stuck on this for a week. Thank you so much dude.